# College Linear Algebra: How to find an explicit formula for a recursive sequence matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, recurrence-relations, diagonalization

I have to find a formula given $a_n$ using the following information: $M^k =PD^k P^{-1}$

I have been given the following information:
$a_1= -1$, $a_2= 1$

The matrix $M$ is $ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\-20 & 9 \\ \end{bmatrix} $.

Furthermore, the exponent $k$ such that $\begin{bmatrix} a_n \\a_{n+1} \\ \end{bmatrix}$ $=$ $M^k$ $\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\a_2 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

Here is where I begin my work:

When I diagonalize the matrix, $D= \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 0 \\0 & 4 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ , $P=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\5 & 4 \\ \end{bmatrix}$  and $P^{-1} =\begin{bmatrix} -4 & 1 \\5 & -1 \\ \end{bmatrix} $

Since $M^k =PD^k P^{-1}$ and

$\begin{bmatrix} a_n \\a_{n+1} \\ \end{bmatrix}$ $=$ $M^k$ $\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\a_2 \\ \end{bmatrix}$,
where $k = n-1$.

Here's where I start my work. I wrote the following:

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 5& 4 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix} 5^k & 0^k \\ 0^k & 4^k \\ \end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix} -4 & 1 \\ 5 & -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

which solves to:

$\begin{bmatrix} a_n \\a_{n+1} \\ \end{bmatrix}$= $\begin{bmatrix} 5^{k+1} & -6*4^k \\ 5^{k+2}& -6*4^{k+1} \\ \end{bmatrix}$

Since $k = n-1$. I concluded that the $a_n$ formula to be:

$5^n - 6*4 ^{n-1}$

However it shows that I got this formula wrong. Can somebody lend a hand?

Comment: It looks right to me.  What is the answer in the book?

Comment: Hi its webwork so I dont know the answer

Comment: I think you are correct.  I checked your calculations in sympy to be sure.

Comment: The given recursion boils down to $a_{n+2}=9a_{n+1}-20a_n$. This recursion has the general solution $a_n = c_1 4^n + c_2 5^n$. So, your calculation is correct. But there might be a discrepancy, if the author of the question had in mind a more common starting vector: $a_{\color{blue}{0}}=-1, a_{\color{blue}{1}}=1$. Then the solution would be $a_n = 5^{n+1}-6 \cdot 4^n$. So, you may recheck the indices of the starting vector in the question.

Comment: Still not working, I will ask the author of the question and get back to you all

Comment: Apparently I had to substitute $n-1= k$. It may be an error on their side though but its all good